# paypal classic asp msxml error on windows server 2008

Tags: paypal, asp-classic, ssl-certificate, serverxmlhttp, msxml6

The following routine works fine from my Win 2003 server to send a pay request to Paypal.

```vb
Set vXMLHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

vXMLHttp.setOption(3) = CERT_PATH

strURL = KEYPOINT &"/AdaptivePayments/Pay"
vXMLHttp.open "POST", strURL, false  

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID", API_USERNAME

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD", API_PASSWORD

'vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE",  API_SIGNATURE

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", REQUEST_FORMAT

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", RESPONSE_FORMAT

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID", APPLICATION_ID

vXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "X-PAYPAL-CERT-PATH", CERT_PATH

vXMLHttp.Send vrequest

vXMLHttp.waitForResponse 5
```

I am moving to WIn Server 2008 R2 and it throws this error on the `.Send()`

> **msxml6.dll error '80072f9a'
>
>   System error: -2147012710.**

I believe I have installed the API certificate correctly because prior to this error, I was getting a cert error.

The MSXML6.dll is version 6.3

Could it be permissions?  Has anyone else had problems migrating paypal to 2008?

Comment: Hey there did you ever get this to work?  Having a similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try;

```vb
Const SXH_OPTION_SELECT_CLIENT_SSL_CERT = 3
Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056

Call vXMLHttp.setOption(SXH_OPTION_IGNORE_SERVER_SSL_CER T_ERROR_FLAGS, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)
```